# How do I remove this duplicate sources.list entry?

Tags: ppa, software-sources

Sometimes, when I run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

or install an app

```
sudo apt-get install
```

I get the error below at the bottom in the gnome-terminal and I can't remove it. I searched for it in the software-sources and in `y-ppa-manager` and I am not sure I want to mess with the sources list since I am a bit of a noob.

```
Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/partner amd64 Packages \
  (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_partner_binary-amd64_Packages)
```